# How to control an alert box with PUPPETEER

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I need to control an box like alert box, like this:
[Image to control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6xpV.jpg)

ok, i tried this:

```
await page.type(String.fromCharCode(37)); // arrow left
await page.type(String.fromCharCode(13)); // arrow enter
```

But it don't work with these boxs..
There is some way to control it?

Comment: This isn't enough information to help, unfortunately. What's the website and the selectors you're working with? Did you try looking at the docs? [`page.type()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagetypeselector-text-options) accepts two arguments: `page.type(selector, text[, options])`. Where is your first parameter, the `selector`? What do you mean by "control it" exactly? Thanks.

Comment: Puppeteer provides an API for handling `alert` boxes => https://chercher.tech/puppeteer/alerts-puppeteer 
For more help please edit the question and add more details.